# React Testing Library, Component can be found using component.getByText but not screen.getByText

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple component I am testing (deliberately simplified to give a minimal reproducible example), where there is a  behavior difference bewteen screen.getByText and the rendered element's getByText method

```
export const GuestGoPaperlessModal: React.FC<Props> = () => {
        return (
        <>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <Leaf size={40} spotColor="#C9DBFE" strokeWidth="0.5" aria-hidden="true"/>
            </div>
            <div className="font-serif text-primary-13126c">Simplify. Go paperless</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I have the following test

```
render(<GuestGoPaperlessModal providerId={1} userPublicId="123"/>);
screen.getByText("Simplify. Go paperless")
```

It fails on the getByText with "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Simplify. Go paperless. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible."

However the following test passes

```
{getByText} = render(<GuestGoPaperlessModal providerId={1} userPublicId="123"/>);
getByText("Simplify. Go paperless")
```

What's going on here? We are on version 12.1.5 of @testing-library/react

Comment: using 14.0.0 @testing-library/react, this works:
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
const GuestGoPaperlessModal = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div>something</div>
      </div>
      <div className="font-serif text-primary-13126c">
        Simplify. Go paperless
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
describe('GuestGoPaperlessModal', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    render(<GuestGoPaperlessModal  />);
    screen.getByText('Simplify. Go paperless');
  });
});
could you share the full code in a sandbox?

Comment: what if you try with a less complex text.
Maybe just a word.

Comment: @PierreCourpron good to hear it works. Let me test it in a sandbox, since that might point to plugins/project specific issues that might be the actual root cause.